How to specific dark colour (color) scheme for all LibreOffice applications except LibreOffice Draw? (Linux)
I find dark mode most suitable for all the LibreOffice applications except LibreOffice Draw.
How can one specify to use a dark application colour (color) scheme for all LibreOffice applications, except for LibreOffice Draw?
In LibreOffice's Options UI, the Application Colours setting does not allow the user to specify any colours specific to LibreOffice Draw except for the Grid colour.
Setting the overall Custom Colours Scheme in that UI seems to change the UI for all LibreOffice applications, not just the LibreOffice application currently running.
I searched the LibreOffice documentation, and could find no command line option to configure such a parameter.  There are the --display and -env command line options/arguments, but it is unclear if there is a way to use either to accomplish this goal.
Answers for Linux are appreciated, particularly for Linux Mint, Ubuntu, and Debian.
